# Java UDP packet only holds 5 bites

Tags: java, sockets, udp

The following code is used to send over a simple string in the following formart "address,porttNum".

Here is the client side:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData());
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bin);

try {
            System.out.println("Data in packet: " + dis.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is the server side:

```
byte[] sbuf = data.getBytes();
        // sbuf = output.getBytes();
        packet = new DatagramPacket(sbuf,
                sbuf.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
try { 
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.send(packet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Say the server sends "abcdefghi", the client only recieves "abcde". I have tried it with multiple test cases and the client always recieves 5 bytes. Can anyone point out where I messed up?

**edit:**
For debugging purposes I even added the following:

```
try {
            System.out.println("Data in packet: " + dis.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

which outputs the right data the client still does not get it.

**edit 2:**
I changed the client side to the following:

```
String data = new String(packet.getData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Data in packet: " + data);
```

It makes no difference.

Comment: Looks good so far. If there are any linebreaks in your input, the ``readLine()`` will mess it up...

Comment: A `DataInputStream` should be matched with a `DataOutputStream`.  Your server code just shows `data.getBytes()`, with no clue as to what `data` was, or how it was generated.  And `DataInputStream#readLine()` is deprecated.

Comment: You might try just converting your bytes to a string using something like `new String(packet.getData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`. I dont see a reason for using a `DataInputStream` here. Could cause problems as @f1sh has pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example code showing construction of a Datagram packet from the bytes of a String, sending it, and reconstruction of the String.

Notice that the buffer for receiving a packet is created much larger than the message that is eventually received.  This is necessary as the the UDP socket will truncate the message to the size of the buffer if it receives a message larger than the buffer.  For example, if the client sent the message "ZYXWV" to the server, and only created the buffer large enough for that message, and then **reused** the buffer for the incoming message, only the first 5 characters of the incoming message would be received.

```
public class DataGram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
        new Thread(new Client()).start();
        new Thread(new Server()).start();
    }

    static class Client implements Runnable {
        DatagramSocket socket;

        Client() throws SocketException {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(1234);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            try {
                try {
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    String msg = new String(packet.getData());
                    System.out.println(msg);
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Server implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1234);
            try (DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket()) {
                String msg = "abcdefghi";
                byte[] buf = msg.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address);
                socket.send(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No DataInputStream or ByteArrayInputStream is used here, since you can directly convert a `String` to `byte[]` and back again.

Comment: I made the suggested edits. No success. I should note that I am threading the server side. Not sure of how that would make a difference though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mjr You will have to post more of your code (reducing it to the bare minimum that still exhibits the problem) before we can help you much further.  I've pointed out that your client is using a `ByteArrayInputStream` and a `DataInputStream` but no such equivalents appear to be used in your server code; a `DataOutputStream` should be used as the source for a `DataInputStream`, etc.  I've pointed out that UDP packets will drop data if you don't specify a buffer large enough.  I've given you a working example to compare with your code.  Without seeing more of your code, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I fixed it. the problem was that I had not changed my original buf from the client side and therefore was only recieving as many letters as the length of the original string that was sent.

Comment: @mjr Glad to hear it is solved.  I hope you still follow the recommendation of not using `readLine()`.  Instead consider `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()` if you are still using `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`.